# How to return 400 error for unique_together constraint violation?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django-Rest-Framework and have a model with the following constraint:

```
unique_together = ("title", "owner")
```

When that error is encountered the server sends a 500 response to the client, but I want to return a 400 error and detail of the constraint, so I can show it to the user. Here is the serializer code:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    title = validated_data.pop('title')
    poll = Poll.objects.create(title=title,
                               slug=slugify(title),
                               **validated_data)
    p = Poll.objects.get(id=poll.id)
    [p.tags.add(tag) for tag in validated_data['tags']]
    return poll
```

The `owner` is coming from the request (i.e. client user):

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    """

    :param serializer:
    :return:
    """
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user,
                    follows=[])
```

I'm not sure where to put the validation code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override serializer's `validate` method like this:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate(self, attrs):
    validated_data = super(WriteoffSerializer, self).validate(attrs)
    poll = Poll.objects.filter(title=validated_data['title'], owner=validated_data['owner').exists()
    if poll:
        raise ValidationError('Poll with such title and owner already exists') 
    return validated_data
```

By default this exception results in a response with the HTTP status code "400 Bad Request".

Comment: Oh, I guess it's a little more complicated because I'm getting 'owner' from the request itself. I'm going to update the OP to reflect this.

Comment: Can I put the same kind of code in `perform_create` in the view?

Comment: Indeed, it works placing your code in the `perform_create` method, using serializer.validated_data. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in `rest_framework.validators.UniqueTogetherValidator` as per the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquetogethervalidator)

```py
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueTogetherValidator

class PollSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Poll.objects.all(),
                fields=['owner', 'title']
            )
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your python function throws error you can always catch it with `try` and `except`

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    try:
        # this code throws error
        ...
        return poll
    except Exception as e:
        # i caught error
        return str(e)
```